# In a matrix created using 2d arrays, is there a way to mark which three columns and rows have the greatest sum?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a question. I'm supposed to create a 2d array, with random numbers from 0 - 9 in between. I'm supposed to find the sum of each row and column, and then find the ones with the top three sums. When I have found those, I need to print an asterisk (*) next to that row, and below that column as well. How would I do so? (I haven't been taught much about arrays, the only array method we can use is Array.length).

Here is my code so far: (It doesn't work)

```java
        int[][] numbers = new int[7][7];
        int rowSum = 0;
        int colSum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        
        int[][] nums = new int[7][2];
            
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {   
            rowSum = 0;
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {   
                int rand = (int)(Math.random()*10);
                numbers[i][j] = rand;
                rowSum += rand;
                
                colSum += numbers[j][counter];
            }
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0) nums[i][j] = rowSum;
                else nums[i][j] = colSum;
            }
            colSum = 0;
            counter++;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) System.out.println("  1 2 3 4 5 6 7"); 
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {   
                if (j == 0) System.out.print(i+1 + " ");
                System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
            }
            
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(nums[i][j] + " ");
            }
            
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Desired output:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 (these rows and columns have random numbers)
2               *
3               *
4
5               *
6
7
  *   *       *
```

Edit:  I managed to get it to work, thank you everyone for your help! This is how I did it: I first calculated the sum of every row and column (using a for-loop), and added those numbers into two different arrays. I then sorted those arrays (from lowest to largest), and the three numbers in the array at the end were the greatest sums of the rows or columns. While printing the matrix, I used an if-else statement to see if the sum equaled any of the last three numbers in the sorted array, and if so, printed an asterisk. This was done using @StaticBeagle's help.

Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are allowed to sort and copy arrays. If you can copy and sort arrays, the following snippet is a solution to the problem:

Let's try to break the problem into bite size steps:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] numbers = new int[7][7];
    int[] rowSums = new int[numbers.length];
    int[] colSums = new int[numbers[0].length];

    // 1. fill 2d array with random values and compute the sums for the rows:
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            numbers[i][j] = rand;
            rowSums[i] += rand;
        }
    }
    // 2. Let's calculate the sum of the colums
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
            colSums[i] += numbers[j][i];
        }
    }
    
    // 3. create helper arrays to hold the sorted sums for the rows and columns
    int[] sortedRowSums = copyArray(rowSums);
    int[] sortedColSums = copyArray(colSums);
    bubbleSort(sortedRowSums);
    bubbleSort(sortedColSums);

    // 4.
    // The last 3 elements should hold the 3 highest values
    // There might be duplicates meaning the sums can be [1 2 3 4 4 4 4]
    // So there's' supposed to be 4 stars
    int maximumOfRowsStart = sortedRowSums[sortedRowSums.length - 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print(rowSums[i] >= maximumOfRowsStart ? "*" : "");
        System.out.println();
    }

    // 5.
    // Similarly for the columns you can apply the same methodology 
    // applied to the rows
    int maximumOfColsStart = sortedColSums[sortedColSums.length - 3];
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; ++j) {
        System.out.print(colSums[j] >= maximumOfColsStart ? "* " : "  ");
    }
}

// Helper ascending sort method
public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                // swap arr[j+1] and arr[j]
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
}

// helper copy array method
public static int[] copyArray(int[] array) {
    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = array[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not too sure about the line where under number 5 where it says `System.out.print(colSums[j] >= maximumOfColsStart ? "* " : "  ");`. We haven't learned that yet, so is there a way to remove and replace that? Also, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Unknownst that's called the [ternary operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator) it's a one liner `if, else`. Basically it's the equivalent of  (pseudo-code)
`if(colSums[j] >= maximumOfColsStart) {print ("* ")} else {print ("  ")}`

Answer (score 1):

After calculating the sums per row and column it is needed to find the indexes of the top N rows/cols.  This can be done using a sorted map (`TreeMap`) using reverse order with the sum as a key and list of indexes in the row/column as a value.  Then top K values are taken from the map to form the list of indexes per row/column.

Example implementation using Stream API:

```java
// create input random 2D square array
final int N = 7;
Random random = new SecureRandom();
int[][] arr = IntStream
        .range(0, N)
        .mapToObj(row -> random.ints(N, 0, 10).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

// calculate the sums per row and column
int[][] sums = new int[2][N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        sums[0][i] += arr[i][j];
        sums[1][i] += arr[j][i];
    }
}

// find the indexes of top sums per row/column 
final int MAX_TOP = 3;
List<Integer>[] tops = Arrays
        .stream(sums)
        .map(r -> IntStream
            .range(0, N)
            .boxed()
            .collect( // build sorted map sum -> list of indexes
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                    i -> r[i], 
                    () -> new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder()), 
                    Collectors.mapping(i -> i, Collectors.toList())
            ))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .limit(MAX_TOP)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
        .toArray(List[]::new);
```

```
// printing

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (i == 0) { // header
        System.out.print("    ");
        IntStream.range(1, N + 1).forEach(ii -> System.out.print(ii + "  "));
        System.out.println('\n' + "-".repeat(3 * N + 3));
    }
    
    // main 2D array
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            System.out.print(i + 1 + ":  ");
        }
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "  ");
    }
    // print sum per row
    System.out.printf("%2d  ", sums[0][i]);

    // print top per row
    if (tops[0].contains(i)) {
        System.out.print("* #" + (tops[0].indexOf(i) + 1));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("-".repeat(3 * N + 3));

// print sums per column
System.out.print("   ");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%2d ", sums[1][i]);
}
// print tops per column
System.out.print("\n    ");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-2s ", tops[1].contains(i) ? "*" : " ");
}
System.out.print("\n   ");
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-2s ", tops[1].contains(i) ? "#" 
        + String.valueOf(tops[1].indexOf(i) + 1) : " ");
}
```

Output:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
------------------------
1:  0  9  0  5  7  8  9  38  * #1
2:  0  1  1  8  3  0  3  16  
3:  8  8  3  4  3  1  5  32  
4:  9  0  1  8  5  6  0  29  
5:  7  4  5  7  1  5  7  36  * #2
6:  5  9  8  7  0  0  3  32  
7:  7  1  3  6  6  3  7  33  * #3
------------------------
   36 32 21 45 25 23 34 
    *        *        *  
   #2       #1       #3
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, but like I said in my question I am only allowed to use the `array.length` method. But, Thank you so much!